How to add additional Kubernetes resources to a Quarkus Helm chart?
How to add additional resources to the Helm chart generated by the Quarkus Helm extension?
Just adding to the src/main/helm folder does not work.
E.g. we need to add a SecretProviderClass and NetworkPolicy resource for which we just want to provide the yaml files.
